# In Cypress how to count elements containing the text?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

In Cypress, I'm trying to count how many elements (in this case how many buttons in li) contain text. When using "contains", the number of returned items is always equal to one because "contains" only gives the first item in the document containing the search text.

```
          cy.get('li')
            .contains('button', 'Submit')
            .its('length')
            .then(elLength => {
              // I want to test here the number of all buttons in li elements containig word 'Submit'
             }
```

Of course, this doesn't work that way,  because *elLength* is always 1 (or 0 if no items found).

Is there any other method in Cypress that can return all elements with text, and I can count them?

Comment: Finally, after getting a very motivating negative vote ;), I found some solution to this problem: `cy.get('li').then($el => {
                cy.wrap($el).find(Cypress.$('button:contains("Submit")'))
                    .its('length').should('eq', expected_number)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cypress `get()` uses the same selectors as jQuery. You can therefor use `:contains` to get all elements containing a text.
As Cypress `contains()` only includes visible DOM elements, you have to add `:visible` to get the same kind of behaviour.

To make sure only one visible button contains "Submit":

```js
cy.get('button:visible:contains("Submit")').should('have.length', 1);
```

To make sure only one visible button inside a "li" element contains the text "Submit":

```js
cy.get('li button:visible:contains("Submit")').should('have.length', 1);
```

To count the "li" elements that contain one or more visible "Submit" buttons:

```js
cy.get('li:has(button:visible:contains("Submit"))').should('have.length', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the right amount of buttons that need to have that label, you could try:

```
cy.get('li').then($el => {
    cy.wrap($el).find(".button").then($els => {
        expect($els.filter(index => $els.eq(index).is(':contains(Submit)'))).to.have.length(your_amount);
 })
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot.